# Why won't modprobe or insmod work when I have the .ko file available?

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, kernel-module

I downloaded a kernel module source for the batman advanced MANET and then called `make` in the directory of the source and let it do its thing.

Once `make` was finished the file batman-adv.ko was available in the folder located in /home/batman-adv-2013.2.0. When I call `modprobe batman-adv` in the directory I get the error:

```
FATAL: Module batman_adv not found.
```

and when I call `insmod batman-adv.ko`:

```
 insmod: error inserting '/home/batman-adv-2013.2.0/batman-adv.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

The operating system I am using is Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)

Have I missed anything that I should have done differently or perhaps the module files need to be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Try to use `depmod -a`

Answer (score 3):

"Unknown symbol" usually implies that the module has a dependency on another module. You can verify which symbol by using `dmesg`, which will tell you what unknown symbol(s) have been encountered. usually the prefix of a symbol (e.g. fat_xxxxx) implies which kernel module is required. `modprobe` will work only for modules which are listed in the modules.dep file.

Comment: Yes, and also try 'nm /home/batman-adv-2013.2.0/batman-adv.ko' to view the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

to add to Technologeeks answer:

`modprobe` will only search for modules in the standard path `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`.
since your `.ko` file is not in that directory, `modprobe` doesn't find it.

the proper way to use your module would be to:

```
make install
depmod -a
modprobe batman-adv
```

- the first line should install the module to a proper location, where all the other tools work with.
- the 2nd line tries to find out all the dependencies needed to use your modules, and puts that info into some persistent place (`lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep`)
- the 3rd line uses the dependency information and loads all dependencies and your module.

Comment: But if you've built it out of tree, don't you use `make modules_install`?  When you do that, I thought it takes care of the depmod.  I'm still fairly green in this area.

Comment: @mark mcmurray Also, when I don't feel like going through that, I just cram it in with `insmod` -- this wont solve your unresolved symbol however!